# redirect to mobile site using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mobile

how do i redirect users to my mobile page ?

i am using this code on htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^desktop
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|iphone|ipod|#opera mobile|palmos|webos" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "acs|alav|alca|amoi|audi|aste|avan|benq|bird|blac|blaz|brew|cell|cldc|cmd-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "dang|doco|eric|hipt|inno|ipaq|java|jigs|kddi|keji|leno|lg-c|lg-d|lg-g|lge-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  "maui|maxo|midp|mits|mmef|mobi|mot-|moto|mwbp|nec-|newt|noki|opwv" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "palm|pana|pant|pdxg|phil|play|pluc|port|prox|qtek|qwap|sage|sams|sany" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "sch-|sec-|send|seri|sgh-|shar|sie-|siem|smal|smar|sony|sph-|symb|t-mo" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "teli|tim-|tosh|tsm-|upg1|upsi|vk-v|voda|w3cs|wap-|wapa|wapi" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "wapp|wapr|webc|winw|winw|xda|xda-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "up.browser|up.link|windowssce|iemobile|mini|mmp" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "symbian|midp|wap|phone|pocket|mobile|pda|psp" [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/mobile [L,R=302]
```

it works for only if i go to site.com it will redirect me to http://example.com/mobile
but i want it to be like, even if i go to http://example.com/page1.php or any other pages it should redirect me to http://example.com/mobile for all mobile users.

please help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, just change

```
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/mobile [L,R=302]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://example.com/mobile [L,R=302]
```

or maybe

```
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://example.com/mobile/$1 [L,R=302,QSA]
```

---

To redirect to a different hostname (sometimes called a "subdomain"), as asked in the comment below, you can do that:

```
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://m.example.com/$1 [L,R=302,QSA]
```

---

And a general remark: I think a http-301 does make more sense than a http-302 for this situation...

Comment: thanks dear it worked but i wanted to ask you 1 question,

Comment: do you know how do i do like. for example my mobile site is on a sub-domain. and i want it to be like when i go to http://example.com/page1.php it should redirect me to http://m.example.com/page1.php also with all other pages

Comment: I added that to the answer.

Comment: Whats the difference between [L,R=302] and [L,R=302,QSA]

Comment: @Black The documentation of the apache rewrite module will answer that question: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule  In short: that "flag" takes care that a potential query string in the requests is preserved during the redirection.